# I'm just beginning to learn C: Can someone explain what the pointers and typecasting are doing in this code?

Tags: c, pointers

//Beginning of a Function:

```
char *encrypt(char *string, size_t length) {
}
```

I am beginning a simple encryption function, and I'm wondering what exactly the above code is carrying out? I am assuming I'm initializing an encrypt function as char pointer, with a memory destination 'string' and size of 'length'

Am I correct?

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at it. Thank you. I was just hoping someone could just quickly verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet

```
char *encrypt(char *string, size_t length) {
}
```

*defines* a function named `encrypt`, which takes a `char *` and a `size_t` as arguments, and returns a `char *`.  As written, the function body is empty and will trigger at least one diagnostic because it isn't returning a value.

It looks like it's meant to take an unencrypted string as the `string` argument, and return the encrypted version of it:

```
char unenc[] = "This is a test";
char *enc = encrypt( unenc, strlen( unenc ) );
```

We're dealing with pointers because of how C treats array expressions.  A *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator - the string "hello" is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  Strings are stored in arrays of character type (`char` for ASCII, EBCDIC, and UTF-8 encodings, `wchar_t` for "wide" encodings like UTF-16).

However, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string *literal* used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of array type is converted ("decays") to an expression of pointer type, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

We defined `unenc` as an array of `char` large enough to hold the string `"This is a test"` (14 characters plus the 0 terminator).  When we pass `unenc` as an argument to `encrypt`, it "decays" from type `char [15]` to `char *`, and what the function actually receives is the address of the first element of the array (`&unenc[0]`).

Array expressions cannot be the target of an assignment, and functions cannot return array types.  However `encrypt` is meant to work internally, it cannot return the encrypted string *as an array*; it can only return a pointer to the first element of the array storing the string.

Now, without knowing the implementation, it's possible that `encrypt` is encrypting the string *in place*, overwriting the original contents of the array, and return that same address:

```
char *encrypt( char *string, size_t length )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    string[i] = replace_char( string[i] );
  return string;
}
```

Since `string` is declared `char *` and not `const char *`, that's a reasonable inference to make.  And it would avoid memory management headaches.  Of course you're destroying your input, so there are tradeoffs there.

If it's not encrypting in place, then the `encrypt` function needs to either allocate new memory, or use memory that's available outside the lifetime of the function (either a global or a local that's been declared `static`, which brings its own headaches):

```
char *encrypt( char *string, size_t length )
{
  char *e = malloc( length + 1 );
  if ( e )
  {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
      e[i] = replace_char( string[i] );
  }
  return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It *defines* (implement) a function named `encrypt`. It possibly *declares* it as well, if it haven't been declared already.

This function takes two arguments:

- One named `string` which is of the type `char *` (pointer to `char`)
- One named `length` which is of the type `size_t`

The function returns a `char *` (pointer to `char`) value.

The function can be called with any kind of variables which are (or can be converted to) pointer to `char` and a `size_t`. For example the following is valid:

```
char some_string[] = "foobar";

encrypt(some_string, strlen(some_string));
```

Comment: The OPs function is _implements_ the function (which BTW does nothing, not even return a value while it is declared to return a `char*`). You should mention this in the answer.